# Word Interop Paragraph.Hyphenation values

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, vsto

How can I enable the Hyphenation of a paragraph in a word document using C# and Office Interop?

I found this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.paragraphs.hyphenation%28v=office.11%29.aspx)...but they are talking about setting the property to boolean values, although the property is a integer. That confuses me.

I tried setting paragraph.Hyphenation to 1, but this resulted in an exception (Value not within range).

Possible values I can set are -1 and 0. Do they represent false (-1) and true (0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ParagraphFormat.KeepWithNext` true is -1 and false is 0. I think this will be consistent across all properties. Better to trial and error.

Comment: ridiculous that true equates to -1, what happened to boolean true being 1?